# SQL Query to get data from magento 1.9

Tags: sql, magento-1.9

sql query for catalog categories needs to be created along with what exists in magento 1.9 and the proper child<>parent relationship should be set.
the products should be mapped to appropriate category and store.

i am expecting to get result in one table only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.